# Submit form on checkbox change and keep built-in browser validation

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My form consists of text input and a checkbox.

The text input cannot be empty upon form submit, hence the `required` parameter.

I want to submit the form on each checkbox change and still keep this built-in validation. Currently, if the text input is empty and I click the checkbox, it WILL submit.

How can keep the validation on checkbox change?

```js
const Form = () => {

    const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()        
        alert('submitted')
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" required />
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => handleSubmit(e)} />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}

const root = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<Form />, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can keep built in validation because `event` is different in your case, one is from checkbox `onChange` and another is from form `onSubmit`. I'd just check condition in `handleSubmit` and create a custom validation for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to trigger the submit button, in this case the html5 validation should run:

```js
const Form = () => {

    const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()        
        alert('submitted')
    }

    const handleChange = (e: any) => {
        const btn = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
        btn.click();
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" required />
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} />
            <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}

const root = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<Form />, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```